# linq to sql continue error

Tags: linq-to-sql, submitchanges

i had an error on a linq query when i tried to do SubmitChanges()

the problem is that what ever i try to do in my project now i'm getting the
same error (i guess the linq still tring to do the Error Change)

how can i clean the pendding changes or deal with that issue otherwise?

Thanx!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reject all changes in a Linq to SQL's DataContext?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259219/how-can-i-reject-all-changes-in-a-linq-to-sqls-datacontext)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove them from the 'queue'.

The simplest is just the call `GetChanges`, and do all the actions in reverse. Eg, Inserts becomes deletes, etc.

[Here](http://xacc.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/datacontextrevertchanges/) is an extension method I wrote that works for simple cases (modify it as you want).

Comment: i think it better to use: db.GetChangeSet().Updates.Clear() for updated, db.GetChangeSet().Inserts.Clear() for new or db.GetChangeSet().Deletes.Clear() for deleted items. Thansks!

Comment: Well that would work, IFF it had a working clear method.... All those lists are readonly so it does not work in practice.