# Clear Context in WPF

Tags: wpf, datacontext

I want to ask how can I clear context if user want to go back in many cases? For example:

```
                _client.Invoice.Add(_invoice);
                _context.Client.Add(_client);
```

I bind and add Invoice and Client information but do not save it in database by using

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

In this case the data still exist in context, What I want to ask about, How can I clear Invoice and Client context without leave window ?

Hope this is clear?

Comment: What is the type of `_context`?

Comment: Are you talking about Entity Framwork?

Comment: refer to following question if `_context` is linq to sql's DataContext : [How can I reject all changes in a Linq to SQL's DataContext?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259219/how-can-i-reject-all-changes-in-a-linq-to-sqls-datacontext). Otherwise you need to explain more about *context*, what kind of context?

Comment: I came here because this was tagged WPF, but I don't see the connection to WPF - is this tag right?